# Allow file access only via cookie

Tags: htaccess, cookies

I need to have groups of PDF files on a site that are protected by different passwords, which I have solved with **WPYog** Documents plugin to create individual document repositories and **Passster** plugin to password protect individual repositories on the site. The goal is not for users to have to register to access the documents.

But now I need to make it impossible to view (download) documents via a direct link. I found some modifications to the `.htaccess` file, but they only take into account the logged in/not logged in user. Is there any possibility to make a link to, for example, only the cookie created by the **Passter** plugin after successful password entry?

Something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yourwebsite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !hotlink\.(pdf) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*???*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(pdf)$ http://yourwebsite.com/ [NC]
```

The cookie file is called **passster**.

Sorry for maybe a stupid question, but I'm not a developer so I'm trying maybe the impossible here.

Comment: "I solve with WPYog Documents plugins to create individual document repositories and Passster plugin to password protect individual repositories" - I don't know how this is implemented, but if documents (PDFs) are password protected (by WordPress) then those documents should not be "directly" accessible at all, regardless of whether a cookie is set or not. (?) Ideally those documents would be stored outside of the public HTML space to begin with (so no additional blocking in `.htaccess` is necessary).